# How can i set on screen keyboard active when phisical keyboard is connected in AOSP source code?

Tags: android, android-source

I have a question, where in the AOSP android 12 source code can I change the setting to display the on-screen keyboard, when the physical keyboard is connected?

I know i can set it in:`Settings > System > Languages & input > Physical keyboard > Use on-screen keyboard` but i want to have this option active as a default after build.

I was looking for this option in:

`/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml`

and

`/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xmlbut without success.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to take a look at onEvaluateInputViewShown() method in InputManagerService.

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-13.0.0_r42:frameworks/base/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.java;l=2068;bpv=0;bpt=0